# C function calculates wrong with pointers

Tags: c, function, pointers

so i've been on trying to coding my first commandline game. I've been coding in C now for about a few months and it's my first coding language. I had no real problems until i came to the point where i had to deal with this pointer conversion.

Here is my function:

```
void attack(int * life, int * armor, char * name){

int difference;
const int damage = 15;

print_Name(name);
printf(" attacks!\n");                                                                       

if((*armor) > damage){
    printf("The armor was able to defend the damage!\n\n\n");
    (*armor) = armor - damage;
}

if((*amor) <= damage){
    printf("Your Armor broke!\n");
    difference = damage - (*armor);
    (*life) = (*life) - difference;
    (*armor) = 0;
    printf("The attack caused %i damage.\n\n\n", difference);
}

else if ((*armor) == 0){
printf("\nThe attack has caused %i damage.\n\n\n", damage);
(*life) = life - damage;
};
```

}

i translated my variables from german into english for a better understandment, but there might eventually be some typos.

the problem is, my game work fine for a few rounds. But after ~20-30 rounds i noticed that the damage output was wrong at some point and now i ran into this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPMYU.png)

i know there is something wrong with my if's and that there is a better way to work around with the pointer... Can you help me with my problem?

Comment: After you've fixed this then you should notice that you need **`else`** instead of `if((*amor) <= damage)`...

Answer (score 1):

If you read the warnings that your compiler emits, they'll tell you exactly what the problem is, as well as how to fix it:

```
q58348638.c:11:18: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning
      to 'int' from 'int *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
        (*armor) = armor - damage;
                 ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                   *(            )
q58348638.c:24:13: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning
      to 'int' from 'int *'; dereference with * [-Wint-conversion]
    (*life) = life - damage;
            ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
              *(           )
```

In case that still isn't clear enough, the problem is that you're setting the value of `armor` to the **address** of `armor` minus the value of `damage`. Instead, you need to set the value of `armor` to the **value** of `armor` minus the value of `damage`, so use `*` before `armor`, just like where you correctly did `(*life) = (*life) - difference;`.

Comment: Ah of course... im coding on Visual Studio Code and it doesn't show me any warnings if the code has no errors, thats why i didn't saw it. Guess i better take my time and use the terminal to compile my code. Thanks for the help and also the reminder!

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow!  Make sure you post code that compiles, runs, and exhibits the problem you are trying to solve.

This code has errors that may or may not be part of your original code.  You've used `damage` instead of `*damage` once, used `armor` instead of `*armor` elsewhere and spelled it `amor` in another place.

One thing that can help cut down on error in your actual code is to use augmented assignment (`+= -= *=` etc.) especially when the object you are modifying is specified by an expression.  For example:

```
*armor -= damage; // subtracts (damage) from (*armor)
```

Another is to turn on all warnings, pay attention to what they warn about. Don't consider your code ready for testing until all warnings are gone.  For GNU gcc and compatible compilers like clang, I use both -Wall and add -Wextra and -pedantic to the command line (or project settings).  Using Visual C++ as a C compiler, use /W4 instead of the default /W3.  This will save you a lot of debugging time.

Note:  You mentioned Visual Studio Code in a comment.  I don't use that.  It seems like a pain to set up compared to Visual Studio or Code::Blocks, but it seems you can specify command line options in your project's `c_cpp_properties.json` file.  Try adding the line:

```
"compilerArgs": [
     "/W4"
]
```